# One freemarker template vs Multiple templates

Tags: xml, performance, templates, include, freemarker

I have a large freemarker template (2000 lines) used to generate a very complex XML document. My problem is that:

1. Maintaining this thing is hell. Difficult to navigate through the template, find the information you want and change it.
2. No clear structure.
3. Testing is also difficult. Each time the previous developers compared the whole resulting XML to an "ideal" XML. When you make the slightest change you have to compare the whole XML instead of being able to compare only the part that would be affected.

My obvious idea is to separate this template to a number of smaller ones, each corresponding to a different "logical" section and then include them to a master template. My only concern, one that i haven't found an answer through searching, is weather having many templates (of course they can be cached) included in a master template, adversely affects performance when compared to the single "large" template approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have that #include inside a loop that doesn't do much per cycle and runs for thousand of times, then maybe it can be noticeably slower. Otherwise I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Actually i sat down and migrated a couple of sections of the big template to smaller ones and wrote a few performance tests comparing the 2 approaches and no significant difference was observed after aggregating the results of 1000 iterations of this tests. So i guess (correct me if i am wrong) that in the end what matters is that especially if you cache this **parsed** "Master" template, the template will be almost identical to the **parsed** "Single Template" version.

Comment: It will turn to the the template cache for each `#include` invocation, again and again, but that's a pretty cheap operation, so yeah, it's practically the same.